# Flutter Table Calendar library error "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'keys' was called on null. " untile data not get fech to calendar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have http call to get events from json and fetch to table calendar library but untile the data did not load it shows error

> "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'keys' was called on null. Reciver:
>   null Tried calling : keys See also: https://flutter"

***HTTP call***

```dart
 Future<Map<DateTime, List<Item>>> getTask() async {
    Map<DateTime, List<Item>> mapFetch = {};
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {});
    String link =
        "https:LINK";
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(link), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      Event event = eventFromJson(res.body);
     for (int i = 0; i < event.items.length; i++) {

        if (event.items[i].start.dateTime == null) {
          mapFetch[event.items[i].start.date] = [event.items[i]];
        } else {
          mapFetch[event.items[i].start.dateTime] = [event.items[i]];
        }
      }
    }
    return mapFetch;
  }
```

*** Initialization ***

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    isLoading = true;
    final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
    _selectedEvents = [];
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getTask().then((val) => setState(() {
            _events = val;
            // print('EVENNT $_events ');
          }));
    });
    super.initState();
   }
```

*** Calendar Library Code ***

```
  Widget _buildCalendar() {
    return TableCalendar(
      locale: 'en_US',
      events: _events,
      onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      formatAnimation: FormatAnimation.slide,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
      availableCalendarFormats: const {
        CalendarFormat.month: 'Month',
      },
      builders: CalendarBuilders(
        selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                '${date.day}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

*After data load error disappears*

Comment: @chunhunghan can u help on this please?

Comment: add code where you are using getTask method.

Comment: add code with `keys` getter call

Comment: start.date , date attribute does not exist in your previous question. unable to simulate, please provide full content of res.body. thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan Events are getting fetched properly but when I am going to open this calendar page for some 5 seconds this error is appearing. When all data get fetched error disappears.

Comment: @chunhunghan the screenshots which I have atteched appears only for 5 seconds. When data loaded to calendar this error disappears and proper events get fetch to calendar. This error appears during data fetching. Can we add await in the calendar so this error should not shown?

Comment: your http job take 5 seconds, _events is null during that time. when _events is still null , show empty content. children: <Widget>[
            _events == null ? Container() : _buildCalendar(),

Comment: or use this because ${date.day} is not ready yet, you can check date == null and show empty Text("").  Center(
              child: date == null? Text("") : Text(
                '${date.day}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            )

Comment: Unable to reproduce your case. please try this WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setTask();      
    });
 
setTask() async {
    _events = await getTask();
    setState(() {});
  }

Comment: addPostFrameCallback call setTask() function use await

Comment: your getTask() has Future.delayed and you can remove it. it was used to simulate network delay

Comment: @chunhunghan Thank you once again my dear friend for your help. It works for me.